I want to call one specific cell into my AppsScript code
I have a spreadsheet for daily appointments and each patients' information is on one row of the spreadsheet.
My code will autocomplete documents based on the patients specific information but the date of service must be listed on the finalized documentation.
I would like the date to be listed in one cell only instead of having an additional column with the date repeated over and over for every patient/row but cannot seem to figure out how to call only one cell - B2 - into the code.
Pretty new and have tried a few possible solutions found but still learning all of this as I go so I cant really give examples of what I have tried
